# What are the products that i can use for my Web Adverstiment?

Tags: ads

Could some please help me know what are the good products that are exist in market to develop and configure my  web adversitments.

I need to do adverstisment on web.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Google Adwords?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to integrate the ad code from an ad network (e.g. [Google AdWords](https://adwords.google.com/) as suggested, [Doubleclick](http://www.doubleclick.com/), Yahoo, etc. etc... see the wikipedia list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Internet_advertising_services_and_affiliate_networks))

Once you sign up with one of these networks they will provide you with HTML/JavaScript or other code (the 'Ad Code') that you can integrate into your application.

Answer (score 1):

BE CAREFUL WITH ADWORDS! The current version of Google adWord DOES NOT support Actionscript 3 (AS3).

Only Actionscript 2 (AS2) is supported, and Google is VERY picky about the kinds of code you use. You are not allowed to create any HTTP requests via Flash. They are afraid you will try to circumvent their adWords tracking/counting system.

There IS a workaround to enable you to use AS3, but it is just a bandage, not a final solution. I have used it over the year or so, and had no problems with it.

Also, ads must be below certain file size in K.

Google's primary advantage with adWords is its almost complete ubiquity: adWords ads are EVERYWHERE.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look for the work-around. It is called "life-jacket". It is a free actionscript flash patch.

You can read about and download it at wordpress(dot)com by searching for "exoboy" or the title "Actionscript, AdWords, and Me."

Hope this helps others since I had to go through #$%$ to figure it out on my own....

Answer (score 0):

If not using simple text Google Adwords as rosehaensse suggested, and you want rich text ads, they're all done in Flash these days.